# debugging scheduling modules in hadoop and storm

Tags: debugging, hadoop, mapreduce, scheduling, apache-storm

I have been studying Big data platforms like **Hadoop** and **Storm** for a while and I'm at the beginning of a research work in the field of **scheduling/resource management**. But I wonder how they (developers of these libraries) manage to **debug the Scheduling Classes**? Do they use a specific tool (IDE) or just use logging/unit testing to control how it's running. Because I think using just logging/testing is too complicated and I can't imagine how to test entire scheduler and subsystems altogether.

The Question is, how can I debug my Algorithm after implementation and integrating it into the platform? Is there a place that I can find a sample to understand the logic of their work?

Because using tools (I use intelliJ IDEA) I can debug user level programs with no problem, but at the system level (Scheduling and Resource Management Classes) this method doesn't work!

Any idea would be appreciated (either on hadoop library or storm).

Comment: You can try "remote debugging" of JVM -- just search the Internet if you don't know how JVM remote debugging works -- there are bunch of examples. Otherwise, many people simple use printf/log debugging -- distributed systems are hard to debug in general...

Comment: thanks for the insight, i will definitely look for it. yeah you're right, debugging distributed systems is hard, but the most hard part is that after each print/log edit in code, the whole library should be recompiled in order to take effect.

Comment: If you change code yes. Therefore, you should instrument you code with different log level and use TRACE level to get all details you need.